# In Ember JS using the get and set functions

Tags: javascript, ember.js

In Ember JS any Ember object you can call

```
this.get('model');
```

or

```
this.get('changeset');
```

On several current examples I've seen the following syntax.

```
const { get } = Ember;

export default Component.extend({

   init() {
       this._super(...arguments);
       let model = get(this, 'model');
       // Do something to a model
   }
});
```

Why would you use this style rather than

```
this.get('model');
```

Answer (score 1):

The difference is in style and also if the object was a POJO (or one that doesn't extend an Ember class) you would need to use `get(this, 'model');` to work.

To reduce cognitive load it would be easier to just remember the one approach that will always work.

That said it appears that the community is moving in the opposite direction, supporting the `this.get('model');` syntax.